# ORA 01858, проблема с датой в динамик SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Существует функция, в которую динамически передаются параметры

```
function test_chg1(p_beg_date date, p_end_date date,
                   selectedTemplates tt_varchar2 default null
                   )  
         return tt_testtest
         pipelined is
```

tt_varchar2 в данном случае самописный тип, который создается

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TT_VARCHAR2 as table of VARCHAR2(500)
```

Дальше в декларации идет определение переменных

```
  flt1     varchar2(32767); -- для сбора selectedTemplates
```

Дальше тело кода:

```
begin
    execute immediate 'select ' || '''and hpc_template_name= ''' ||
                      ' || listagg(val,' || ''' or hpc_template_name = ''' ||
                      ')WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY val) from (select ' ||
                      'chr(39) || column_value || chr(39)' ||
                      'val from table (:selectedTemplates)a )'
      into flt1
      using selectedTemplates;
    fltAll := flt1;
    for cr in 
( with cm as (select nomer, planned_start, hpc_template_name, assign_dept
          from stg_hp_cm3rm12 
          where trunc(planned_start) between p_n_date and p_e_date
          || fltAll 
           )
  loop
    insert into Test_chg (nomer, planned_start, assign_dept, hpc_template_name)
           values (cr.nomer, cr.planned_start, cr.assign_dept, cr.hpc_template_name);
  end loop;
end test_chg1;
```

Так много экранирований, потому что execute immediate все время валился с ошибкой, chr(39) это ', которая нормально преобразуется. Вопрос заключается вот в чем:
При попытке войти в for, вылетает ошибка ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
В документации написано, что проблема в формате даты. Приводил к дате явно и внутри самой функции и внутри селекта, пробывал извращения по типу:

```
    execute immediate 'select to_date(trunc(sysdate), '|| '''dd.mm.yyyy ''' || ') 
from dual' into n_date;
    p_n_date := to_date(n_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy');
```

Везде валится с ошибкой. Кто-нибудь может подсказать, как корректно указать функции временной промежуток, либо сделать преобразования. что бы он не вылетал с ошибкой?

Comment: Что у вас за дичь в коде??? Зачем `'select to_date(trunc(sysdate), '|| '''dd.mm.yyyy ''' || ') from dual'`, когда можно просто `'select to_date(trunc(sysdate), ''dd.mm.yyyy '') from dual'`? Зачем вообще получать дату через `execute immediate`, если в лучшем (!) случае у вас будет ровно тот же результат, что и после простого `p_n_date := trunc(sysdate);`? Вы усложняете на пустом месте.

Comment: Почитал внимательнее - `execute immediate` вам вообще не нужен, перепишите аккуратно без него. Глядишь, проблемы сами рассосутся.

Comment: Я же говорил, что пробовал извращения. Явно преобразовывал.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос описание что такое `stg_hp_cm3rm12` и объявление переменных `p_n_date` и `e_n_date`.

Comment: Что функция делает? Дайте пример данных, что дано, что ожидается. В текущем виде это вообще не функция, так как она ничего не возвращяет.

Comment: Разве по синтаксису не понятно, что stg_hp_cm3rm12 это таблица?

Comment: Непонятно. Во-первых, это может быть view (и ошибка может быть внутри view, например), во-вторых, типы данных столбцов имеют значение в данном случае.

Comment: Решил данную проблему, всем спасибо за помощь

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что функция не могла понять входящий параметр. Необходимо явно указать, что это дата.

```
sql_string := 'with cm as (select nomer, planned_start, hpc_template_name, assign_dept
              from stg_hp_cm3rm12  where trunc(planned_start) between ' ||
      'to_date 
      (''' ||
      p_beg_date ||''','|| '''DD-MON-YY '')' ||' and to_date(''' || p_end_date || ''''|| ',' || '''DD-MON-YY'')' 

      ||sql_where ;
```

Comment: Ответ неправильный. Надо было параметры `p_beg_date` и `p_end_date` объявить как дату - это и будет "явно указать, что это дата". Я ведь не зря спрашивал, где и как они объявлены. И не надо все пихать в dinamic sql, надо делать ровно наоборот.

Comment: Входные параметры p_beg_date и p_end_date объявлены как дата. Твой комментарий лишен смысла, потому что если я использую курсор, для сбора этих данных, то при формировании финального запроса у меня получается конструкция вида
where trunc(planned_start) between 03-MAR-18 and 18-MAR-18

Comment: Если `p_beg_date` - это дата, то писать `to_date(p_beg_date, 'DD-MON-YY')` - это просто бомба для потомков, которая рванет неизвестно когда.

Comment: А дата с датой сравнивается как `planned_start between p_beg_date and p_end_date`. Если надо округление - то `trunc(planned_start) between trunc(p_beg_date) and trunc(p_end_date)`